# Yii2: How can I get table columns which have equal not empty data in two columns in the same record

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, yii2

I want to select fields from SQLite database using ActiveQuery where two columns has equal not empty values.

I need such resulting SQL as example:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_sent = 0 AND file_size = downloaded_size AND file_sha1 = downloaded_sha1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked for such solution:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

    $messages = Messages::find()
        ->where([
            'file_downloaded' => 1,
        ])
        ->andWhere(['=', 'msg_sent', 0])
        ->andWhere(['=', 'file_size', new Expression('`downloaded_size`')])
        ->andWhere(['=', 'file_sha1', new Expression('`downloaded_sha1`')])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

// to debug raw SQL I have used the following:
$query = = Messages::find()
            ->where([
                'file_downloaded' => 1,
            ])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'msg_sent', 0])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'file_size', new Expression('`downloaded_size`')])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'file_sha1', new Expression('`downloaded_sha1`')]);
echo var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you activeRecord class  is named  MyModel

```
  $models = MyModel::find()
          ->where(['msg_sent'=> 0, 
                   'file_size'=>'downloaded_size',
                   'file_sha1' =>'downloaded_sha1'])
          ->all();
```

and if don't work hashed  format for where you can use the literal format as

```
   $models = MyModel::find()
    ->where('msg_sent = 0 and file_size= downloaded_size and file_sha1 = downloaded_sha1')
    ->all();
```

Comment: Thank you, @scaisEdge, it is first thing I have tried but it does not work.

Comment: I have the following SQL then I use your advice: string(149) "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE ((`file_downloaded`=1) AND (`file_size`='downloaded_size') AND (`file_sha1`='downloaded_sha1')) AND (`msg_sent` = 0)" I need db fields instead of strings with column names

Comment: answer updated .. with another where format .. hope is useful